# Attempted to load class Error Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

My problem is, I am trying to execute a command, but give me the next error:

> Attempted to load class "XMLReport" from namespace
>   "BusinessName\Core\LibraryDatabaseBundle\Repository".     Did you
>   forget a "use" statement for
>   "BusinessName\Core\LibraryDatabaseBundle\Entity\XMLReport"?

The repository class is using the namespace:

```
namespace Mundoreader\Core\LibraryDatabaseBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Mundoreader\Core\LibraryDatabaseBundle\Entity\Library;

/**
 * Class XMLReportRepository
 *
 */
class XMLReportRepository extends AbstractRepository
{/*code
}
```

The command class is:

```
class GenerateXMLCommand extends AbstractCommand
{

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('library:reports:generateXML')
            ->setDescription('Generate XML');
    }    
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
        {
            $statusToDo         = $this->xmlReportRepo->countAllStatusToDo();

            if($statusToDo)
            {

                //XML BBDD
                $emXML          = new XMLReport();
                $libraryXML     = $emXML->getLibrary();
                $isbnXML        = $emXML->getISBN();
                $toDateXML      = $emXML->getReportDateEnd();
                $fromDateXML    = $emXML->getReportDateStart();
                $arrayXMLInfo = array(
                    ['fromDate']    => $fromDateXML,
                    ['toDate']      => $toDateXML,
                    ['library']     => $libraryXML,
                    ['isbn']        => $isbnXML
                );
    /*More Code 
    }
```

I dont know where is the error, because I call repository in:

```
$statusToDo         = $this->xmlReportRepo->countAllStatusToDo();
```

In the extend class I have the route:

```
abstract class AbstractCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->xmlReportRepo = $this->doctrine->getRepository('MrLibraryDatabaseBundle:XMLReport');
    }
}
```

PD: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Did you add "use BusinessName\Core\LibraryDatabaseBundle\Entity\XMLReport" at the top of GenerateXMLCommand?

Comment: Yes, I did. So I dont know where is the problem.

Comment: It looks like you try to use XMLReport class in XMLReport XMLReportRepository . Can you show XMLReportRepository class code and use block for GenerateXMLCommand class

Comment: Have you added repository annotation to XMLReport entity?

Comment: Please add the beginning of the command class file in your question.

Comment: @AnnaAdamchuk Umm what Do I must add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check repository class in your mapping definition. There should be something like this:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    //...
}
```